# How to connect Netty Server with database?

Tags: java, mongodb, netty

Is there any code example where server written via Netty framework uses database relational or document-oriented for example MongoDB in order to answer clients request from database query and send to client? Thanks in advance?
P.S.
I'm newbie in Netty.

Comment: Please provide any  attempts of your own. Otherwise people will feel like they do the work for you.

Comment: Don't be so greedy guys, i'm a newbie!

Comment: that you need is just java develop... a quick search in the web will provide to you an answer.